# Plugin with option to disable itself on certain products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a plugin that makes a few changes to the product pages in woocommerce and i'd like to add a checkbox if the user wants to disable it for certain products.
I managed to insert the checkbox on the product edit page, but it's possible to verify if it's checked before loading the plugin?

I tried like this, but nothing happens:

```php
global $product;
if ($product) {
   $customAttributes = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'custom_attributes', true );
   if ( isset($customAttributes['disabled']) && $customAttributes['disabled'] == 1 ) {
      return;
   }
}
```

I searched a lot and tried other things, but i couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I always create a plugin and put it in the `mu-plugins` folder so you can do the check before any plugin is loaded.

Could you try the `option_active_plugins` hook?

```
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', function( $plugins ){

    global $product;

    if ( $product ) {
        $customAttributes = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'custom_attributes', true );

        if ( isset( $customAttributes['disabled'] ) && $customAttributes['disabled'] == 1 ) {
            $unload_plugins[] = "my-plugins/my-plugin.php";
            $plugins = array_diff( $plugins, $unload_plugins );
        }
    }

    return $plugins;
} );
```

If needed, maybe wrap it in a `wp` or `init` action, but `get_post_meta` should work there.

Comment: It works, but it doesn't... I created a plugin in the mu-plugins folder and i did as you told and now it is reading the meta, but it isn't disabling the plugin. I'm assuming i have to replace `my-plugins/my-plugin.php` with `plugin-path/plugin-main-filename.php`, right?

Comment: Ok, that's weird. I did some testing and it's actually removing the plugin from the $plugins array, but it loads anyway. I tried with different plugins and the same happens: they are removed from the array, but it does not disable them.

Comment: Hi, Could you be a bit more specific?

How have you checked that it doesn't disabled? By calling a function from that plugin somewhere in a template file or so?


And you should indeed replace plugin-path/plugin-main-filename.php with the path to the plugin you want to unload / remove.

Comment: I know it's not disabled because it's doing what it's supposed to do (replacing the variation select box with buttons). I tried with different plugins and all of them are removed from the $plugins array, but when the page loads, all of them are working as they were not removed.
I think another plugin may be interfering somehow.
Anyway, i gave up and used a javascript to do what i wanted. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry to hear, but glad it al worked out!